# How to get reference to parent view controller in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I know in CocoaTouch there is the parentViewController property for this but there seems to no such property in Cocoa for OSX development. How can I ref the parent view controller in a sub view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind! I'm an idiot! I've checked for this in a View class, not in a View Controller class. The NSViewController does indeed have a parentViewController property.